# How can I sign out of the GitKraken client?

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitkraken

I'm using a public computer and I can't figure out how I can sign out my account in the desktop client for Ubuntu. I can't find a logout button. My GitKraken account is connected to GitHub, and I need a way to sign out.

Comment: There is no 'Logout' in the GitKraken app. 2.5 years later, still, this most basic functionality does not exist.

Answer (score 31):

For **macOS** and **Unix-like**:

`rm -rf ~/.gitkraken` should do the trick.

I couldn't find any UI to do it otherwise.

*Btw it removes all profiles and conf*

Comment: Worked for MacOS.

Comment: @rineez did you find another path to the `.gitkraken` folder? So that I can update the answer?

Comment: Sorry. It is working now actually. I guess I had done something wrong first(I can't remember what had happened), so this command didn't work and I ended up changing the email address in my account. First I was using an email id provided by my previous client. Now I tried deleting the directory directly through my file explorer and it worked. By the way I'm using version 6.5.1 now.

Answer (score 21):

I just ran into this issue myself and I seem to have found a workaround for it.

Exit GitKraken and go to the AppData folder and delete the GitKraken profile. e.g. Go to C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken\ and delete the profiles folder. When you restart GitKraken, you should be signed out and can then sign in to a new account.

Comment: I've had the same issue on Windows and deleting C:\Users\{YourUsername}\AppData\Roaming\\.gitkraken\config worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Nothing short of uninstalling/reinstalling the application (deleting the settings folder noted above, not just the profile folder) sufficed.  I have written Axosoft a support email request explaining how ugly this is and asking if they might implement a "logout" or "switch account" menu option.

Comment: I wiped the entire appdata folder for it and it still has me signed in....

Answer (score 10):

There is an official way (see below), but it does not seem to be enough (
see comments)

[Mahdi Moqadasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5853262/mahdi-moqadasi) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416414/how-can-i-sign-out-of-the-gitkraken-client/53418436#comment96273713_53418436):

> I tried to sign out from all synced servers (github, gitlab and bitBucket) and edit personal information of my own.
> Actually There was no account on GitKraken, but was logged in by GitHub.
> So when I signed out of them and sign in my own, there was no problem anymore

---

[Douglas Gaskell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547347/douglas-gaskell) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416414/how-can-i-sign-out-of-the-gitkraken-client/53418436#comment112476139_53418436):

> On Windows, there is a hidden `.gitkraken` folder under `AppData/Roaming/`

---

Original answer:

From [GitKraken documentation](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/github#github-authentication):

> To authenticate with GitHub, navigate to the upper right corner to access Preferences Authentication.

[image: https://support.gitkraken.com/img/documentation/integrations/github/preferences.png]

Try to use "Sign in with a different account", and see if that is not enough to log you out.

You should be able, if you are connected, to click disconnect:

[image: https://support.gitkraken.com/img/documentation/integrations/github/generate-ssh@2x.png]

[qvpham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6050822/qvpham) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416414/how-can-i-sign-out-of-the-gitkraken-client/53418436?noredirect=1#comment106874340_53418436):

> Just a hint: You can find it under the menu File too

Comment: Didn't work for me. I managed to log in with my GitHub account but someone else's account was still logged in in GitKraken.

Comment: @GuiRitter me too. probably I must reinstall it :\

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi OK, let me know if re-installing gitkraken fixes the issue.

Comment: no, it's not fixed! I tried to sign out from all synced servers (github, gitlab and bitBucket) and edit personal information of my own. Actually There was no account on gitKraken, but was logged in by github. so when I signed out of them and sign in my own, there was no problem anymore

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: In my version of GitKraken, there is no "Sign into a different account" option.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum It is possible this has changed since I wrote this answer.

Comment: Thank you, your solution with `Sign into a Different Account` works for me. Just a hint: You can find it under the menu `File` too. But it may be isn't the right answer for the above question.

Comment: @qvpham Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Reinstalling it does not clear the signin... And if you don't have a 2nd account you can't sign into it, and clear your credentials.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell That seems cumbersome. How did you solve this in your case? Has any of the other suggestions in this page worked?

Comment: Nope, nothing has worked thus far. I've even wiped it's appdata folder, reinstalled, and I'm still signed in... The "sign in from another account" does not sign you out unless you create another account and sign into it.

Comment: Found it, on windows there is a hidden `.gitkraken` folder under `AppData/Roaming/`

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Great! Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution to logout of a GitKraken account w/o deleting all other settings.

In the `.gitkraken` folder there exists a file called `config`. In this file all gitkraken related options and settings have been set via a json object. To remove your logged in GitKraken account, you need to replace the `registration` attribute with an empty json object.

Before:

```json
{
  "lastUpgradeScriptRun": "v7.5.0",
  "appId": "xxxx",
  "registration": {                          <== THIS ONE
    "email": "xx@xxx.de",
    "name": "xxx xxx",
    "status": "activated",
    "trialStatus": null,
    "loginType": "github",
    "date": "xxxxxxx",
    "EULA": {
      "version": "7.5.0",
      "status": "agree_verified"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

After:

```json
{
  "lastUpgradeScriptRun": "v7.5.0",
  "appId": "xxxx",
  "registration": {},
  ...
}
```

The exact file path of the `config` file depends on your OS:

- Windows: `C:\Users\<YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken\config`
- Unix-based: `/home/<YOUR USERNAME>/.gitkraken/config`

You can edit this file with every editor you like (e.g. vim, nano, Editor, Notepad++, VSCode, ...) but please be sure to close GitKraken before editing the file.

Answer (score 1):

For me on **Windows**, uninstalling and/or deleting the AppData did not work.
Had to *open a repo* then I could select an option from a top right menu like in VonC's Answer

Answer (score 1):

It's conveniently the one of the few options that's hidden in the File menu for some reason.

[image: File > Sign into Different Account]

Comment: Note that this does not sign you out, you have to actually sign into another account to be signed out. There is no method that actually signs you out of this application...

Answer (score 0):

Click the button with the three horizontal lines next to your profile picture in the top right and select "sign into a different account"